# ForEach Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql, foreach, sql-server-2012, iteration

I have a list of values that, i.e.

```
in ('1xxx','12xx','21xx','98xx','00xx')
```

I want to use for an insert script. How can a write a for loop in SQL Server using each value within the loop? I'm think something like.

```
For value in ('1xxx','12xx','21xx','98xx','00xx')
  select value
endloop;
```

**Im trying to simply this**

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeCard]
    VALUES
            ('test'+Right(NewId(),12),'6121126800','5102289289',CONVERT(DATE,'01-01-2013'),CONVERT(DATE,'01-01-2013'),20,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL )
    GO

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeCard]
    VALUES
            ('test'+Right(NewId(),12),'6121126800','5102289289',CONVERT(DATE,'01-08-2013'),CONVERT(DATE,'01-08-2013'),20,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL)
    GO


    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeCard]
    VALUES
            ('test'+Right(NewId(),12),'6121126800','5102289289',CONVERT(DATE,'01-15-2013'),CONVERT(DATE,'01-15-2013'),20,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL )
    GO
....
```

I have to insert these records for several testing scenarios.

Comment: 1. create temp table. 2. fill it with items. 3. create cursor on the table. 4. iterate using the cursor.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have`FOR EACH`, it has `DO WHILE`:[Clicky](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx)  But there are probably better ways to handle this than a loop, or cursors.

Comment: Where does this list come from? Your best bet is to start 'thinking in sets' rather than iteration. If your list came from a query, you could easily insert the result into another table

Comment: Why do you need to use a loop at all? Tell us what you're really doing inside the loop - usually this is the worst way to achieve something in SQL.

Comment: @n8wrl these are values that were passed to me manually, ie. via email

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'm trying to insert record for each id in the list. I have to insert 4 records for each month within a given year. Above I will post how I am currently doing it.

Comment: 4 rows for each month, but you have 5 values? Can you explain better please?

Comment: @AaronBertrand please look at the update

Comment: And now I don't understand where the `'1xxx','12xx','21xx','98xx','00xx'` values come into play. They aren't mentioned in the code in your update.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Those values I inserted manually, they fill the 3rd value in the insert statements i.e. '5102289289'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need expensive loops, cursors or functions to build a set from these values you've been handed manually.

```
DECLARE @start DATE = '20130101', @now DATETIME2(7) = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

;WITH months AS 
(
  -- we need 12 months
  SELECT TOP (12) m = number FROM master.dbo.spt_values 
  WHERE type = 'P' ORDER BY number
),
-- we need a week in each month, starting at the 1st
weeks AS (SELECT w FROM (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3)) AS w(w)),
dates AS 
(
  -- this produces a date for the first 4 weeks of each
  -- month from the start date
  SELECT d = DATEADD(WEEK,w.w,DATEADD(MONTH,m.m,@start)) 
  FROM months AS m CROSS JOIN weeks AS w
),
vals AS 
(
  -- and here are the values you were given
  SELECT v FROM (VALUES('1xxx'),('12xx'),('21xx'),('98xx'),('00xx')) AS v(v)
)
-- INSERT dbo.TimeCard(column list here please)
SELECT 
  'Test' + RIGHT(NEWID(),12),
  '6121126800',
  vals.v,
  dates.d,
  dates.d,
  20,
  @now,
  NULL
FROM dates CROSS JOIN vals
ORDER BY vals.v,dates.d;
```

This should return 240 rows (12 months * 4 weeks * 5 values as supplied in your question). When you've manipulated the output to be what you expect, uncomment the INSERT (but please get in the habit of putting a column list there).

Comment: What does the Where type = 'P' represent on line 7?

Comment: @AntarrByrd it limits the output to the sequence of *unique* numbers belonging to stored procedures. If you don't filter this way, you can get multiple values of 1, multiple values of 2, etc. Compare `SELECT TOP (10) number FROM master.dbo.spt_values;` with `SELECT TOP (10) number FROM master.dbo.spt_values WHERE type = 'P';`

Comment: You could accomplish something similar using `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of the actual value, but that is more code from the start, then you also have to subtract 1 to get 0 as part of the result...

Comment: LINQ is terrible and definitely teaches you the wrong things about databases.

Answer (score 1):

If you have comma delimited string use some of these 4 functions that returns table (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amitjet/archive/2009/12/11/sql-server-comma-separated-string-to-table.aspx). 
Insert returned data in temp table with identity column (1,1).

After that loop through table with cursor or using previously created identity column.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a cursor, but you'll need to put this `('1xxx','12xx','21xx','98xx','00xx')`

in something like this

```
select '1xxx','12xx','21xx','98xx','00xx'
```

More information about cursor:

http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180169.aspx